# How to load the state of checkboxlist in database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I got 1 checkboxlist with 6 checkboxes inside it (below is my database)

```
id       : int
interest : bit
```

When I click one checkbox, the value is saved to my database as `TRUE`. Here is my code:

```
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tbinterest(interest) VALUES(@interest)"

Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@interest", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()
End Using
```

But somehow, when I load the page, it does not show the checked state (checked/unchecked). Here is my code in page load. Can you help me out? Thanks.

```
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)     
    Dim objCmd_team As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT [interest] FROM [tbinterest]", myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = objCmd_team.ExecuteReader()

    While (objReader.Read())
        Dim currentCheckBox As ListItem = chkApprovers.Items.FindByText(objReader("interest"))

        If currentCheckBox IsNot Nothing Then
            currentCheckBox.Selected = True
        End If
    End While     
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be correct.. please check this line with break point that listitem has value or not.

Dim
currentCheckBox As
ListItem =
chkApprovers.Items.
FindByText(objReader
("interest"))

If listitem is nothing then try this

Dim
currentCheckBox As
ListItem =
chkApprovers.Items.
FindByText(objReader.Item
("interest").ToString)

And one more thing, you are saving only bit value as interest then how did you match this with your checkbox.
you can match only with checkboy text value or id value

Hope this help.

Comment: Oh , so how can i match with bit value ?